# Why are the angular 2 boostrap directives provided by valor-software?

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have noticed, that the most popular angular 2 boostrap directives are provided by Valor-Software, a private Company.
How did it happen, that their Distribution is more popular than a community driven one? Is Valor-Sofwtware's behaviour generally accepted?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "more popular" - how did you measure this?

Comment: Okay I agree it is a head to head race:) ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap has 2461 Stars and valor-software/ng2-bootstrap has 2460 stars. But still valor software ranks number one in google when entering "angular 2 bootstrap".